# How to generate a copy of an element in the receiving div, once the original element is dropped?

Tags: javascript, html

So, for example I drag the "HI" div into the "DRAG HERE" div; after it has been dragged "HI" will be removed from the first div. But what I want instead is that after it has been dragged to another div it should generate another "HI" div.

```js
/**
  * 
  Function that is executed when dragging the element. 
  **/

function start(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.effecAllowed = 'move'; // Defines the effect of moving (it is the default)
  e.dataTransfer.setData("Text", e.target.id); // Pick up the item to be moved
  e.target.style.opacity = '0.4';
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed is finished dragging the element.
**/
function end(e) {
  e.target.style.opacity = ''; // Restores the opacity of the element

}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a dragging element enters the element from which it is called.
**/
function enter(e) {
  return true;
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a dragging element is on the element from which it is called.
* Returns false if the object can be dropped in that element and true otherwise.
**/
function over(e) {
  if ((e.target.className == "boxes") || (e.target.className == "boxes2"))
    return false;
  else
    return true;
}

/**
* 
Function that is executed when a draggable element is dropped on the element from which it is called.
**/
function drop(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default action of the dropped element from being executed.
  var elementoArrastrado = e.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(elementoArrastrado)); // Place the dropped element on the element from which this function was called

}
```

```html
<div id="select" ondragenter="return enter(event)" ondragover="return over(event)" ondrop="return drop(event)">
  <div id="select1" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)">
    HI


  </div>
</div>
<div id="from" ondragenter="return enter(event)" ondragover="return over(event)" ondrop="return drop(event)">
  <div id="from1" draggable="true" ondragstart="start(event)" ondragend="end(event)">

    DRAG HERE

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited your question to include a snippet, which should the show the code working (or not) in its current form. You may wish to update that snippet (perhaps showing the relevant CSS) in order to ensure it's doing what you describe in your question.

Comment: what are the changes you made?

Comment: To run the snippet just click on the blue 'Run code snippet' button; to see the changes you can click on the 'edited *N* hours ago' link above the name of the person who edited the question, in this case that's my name just to the left of your own (assuming you're using the desktop version of the site, if you're using mobile or the app I'm afraid I'm not quite sure).

Answer (score 0):

What it sounds like you would like to do is generate the new 'HI' `div` after the drag and drop has been completed, so I assume in the `drop(e)` callback function.

You could generate your 'HI' div manually with the help of JavaScript, so somewhere in that function you could do the following with DOM manipulation:

```
var div = document.createElement("div");
// here set a bunch of attributes you'd like to match the div in your HTML
div.setAttribute("id", "select1");
div.setAttribute("draggable", "true");
div.setAttribute("ondragstart", "start(event)");
div.setAttribute("ondragend", "end(event)");

// add the text portion 'HI' to your div
var text = document.createTextNode('HI');
div.appendChild(text);

// append the 'HI' div to body, header or whatever div you'd like
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

So basically you would create your custom div on the go like this and add it whenever you'd like. You could also place this in a separate function called something like `generateDiv()` and call that to get the element filled up with attributes and such, and then simply append.

Hope this is helpful!